# Sending Lambda Function's output as an SNS notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have written a lambda function to create automatic snapshots everyday at a particular time. But, at times, lambda function does not run successfully. It returns an error. But, I never know that until I sign in to my console.

So, I want to know when it throws an error. By doing this, I could know if my lambda function is running properly. It would be better if I get a notificaton when it does not work properly.

Can I get the output of that lambda function as an SNS notification?

Comment: You need to look into using AWS CloudWatch and CloudWatch Logs to monitor your Lambda executions.

Comment: Ohh...is there no other way to do it without logging into console?

Comment: Is there no other way to do what exactly? CloudWatch can alert you when metrics go over a pre-defined threshold, and CloudWatch Logs can alert you when certain text appears in your logs.

Comment: Yaaa...I got u.. thank you